# Angular 5.2 - bypass form validation for [routerLink] while keeping focus

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular5, angular2-forms

**I have completely reworded this question and included a complete code sample.**

I have an intermittent issue where clicking the button sometimes shows the validation error message, instead of executing the router.nagivate command.  Then, I have to click it a second to work.  As I said, this is intermittent.  The solution needs to include the focus behavior of the sample below, or an alternative way to focus on input html tags.  Sometimes, I only have to click once.  Why?  And, how can I control this behavior so that it is not random?

I am posting two test components to demonstrate the issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**test.component.html**

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm">
    <h2>Scan Part</h2>
    <input id="partNum" type="number" class="form-control" required [correctPart]="orderShipDetail?.UPC" name="partNum" [(ngModel)]="model.partNum" #partNum="ngModel" #partNumRef  />
    <div *ngIf="partNum.invalid && (partNum.dirty || partNum.touched)" class="text-danger">
        <p *ngIf="partNum.errors.required">PartNum is required.</p>
        <p *ngIf="partNum.errors.correctPart">Please scan the correct part. </p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="onClickCartonPartButton()">Carton Parts</button>
</form>
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

class TestForm {
    constructor(
        public partNum: string = '') {
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {

    @ViewChild('partNumRef') partNumRef: ElementRef;

    model: TestForm = new TestForm();
    public focusedElement: ElementRef;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        this.focusedElement.nativeElement.focus();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.focusedElement = this.partNumRef;
    }

    onClickCartonPartButton() {
        try {
            this.router.navigate(['/test2', 1006, 1248273, 1234]);
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**test2.component.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/test', 1006, 1248273, 1234, 5 ]">click this</a>
```

**test2.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test2',
  templateUrl: './test2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test2.component.scss']
})
export class Test2Component implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Add these routes to the app.module.ts**

```
{ path: 'test/:empId/:orderNumber/:licensePlate/:orderLine', component: TestComponent },
{ path: 'test2/:empId/:orderNumber/:licensePlate', component: Test2Component },
```

Comment: Can you try adding a (click) event to the buttons and fire routerLink from there? Before firing the router, output a console.log(clickEvent); maybe you'll could use event.stopPropagation() to avoid form validation.

Comment: @JoeriShoeby Thanks for nudging me to do that.  It was part of the solution.  I also needed to  define a template reference variable for each button along with the associated ViewChild definition in the .ts file.  Then, I checked the value attribute of that variable in ngAfterViewChecked.  Strange thing is I never set the value attribute.  I wonder if this extra work created a time delay which allowed the click event to fire and navigate away before the focus() method could run in ngAfterViewChecked.  I don't know.  But, thanks again for the nudge.

Comment: Strange thing indeed that Angular detects a page change as a form submission to ..

Comment: I take it back.  My "solution" was not a solution.  this.cartonPartsButton.value was undefined and therefore this.focusedElement.nativeElement.focus() never fired.  Consequently, the buttons worked, but the textbox did not have its focus.

Comment: Simplified question and added a complete code sample.

Comment: Could you make a demo?

Comment: @Vega Don't know what you mean by demo.  I think I found a solution, see below.

Comment: Change ngOnInit to ngAfterViewInit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove partNum.touched from *ngIf in the validation message div, like this...

```
<div *ngIf="partNum.invalid && partNum.dirty" class="text-danger">
    <p *ngIf="partNum.errors.required">PartNum is required.</p>
    <p *ngIf="partNum.errors.correctPart">Please scan the correct part.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Vega I didn't know that.  What happens when I used the template variable name as id?

Comment: The demo link says "Unexpected value 'TestComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation."  But, app.module.ts looks good to me.

Comment: @Vega I've been trying to get that demo to work, but whenever I click on the "CartonParts" button from the Test component, the route shifts to the Test2 component, but the html rendered by the Test2 component looks like Test component html.  confused.

Answer (score 0):

Set `type="button"` on the two hyperlinks to avoid submit

> A button element with no type attribute specified represents the same
>   thing as a button element with its type attribute set to "submit".

Or put the two hyperlinks outside of the form

Comment: Vince, tried both suggestions, but neither worked.  Updated question to reflect renaming <a> to <button> and addition of type property set to button.